# What keyboard shortcuts would let me temporarily change the font size in a MobaXterm terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, fonts, mobaxterm

I was excited to learn that you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the scroll wheel on the mouse to change the font size in MobaXterm. Later, I thought I found a key combination that did the same thing, but I can't remember what it was (or if I just imagined it). I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> and several other combinations to no avail.

You can also right click and select `increase font size` or `decrease font size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the upper menu go to `Settings/Configuration`, and then under the `Toolbar` menu add buttons for `Zoom in` and `Zoom out` to be displayed.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Does that really activate keyboard shortcut as asked in the question?

Comment: This is so useful and I haven't seen an alternative yet, so I'm accepting this as the answer. Thank you for being brave enough to provide a helpful solution even though it didn't directly answer the original question!

Comment: Thanks again! I gave you the bounty because I find your answer so useful. I use it practically every day.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

1. If you are using keyboard it is :- View -> Zoom in/Zoom out.
2. If using mouse pad :- ctrl + scroll for zoom out and zoom in

Answer (score 0):

I could get the zoom in/out function by tapping two fingers inward to zoom in and back out in the mouse pane on my hp laptop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the font size, but Like most of the tools it supports `ctrl + scroll` to zoom in and zoom out.